# Generator of a fundamental group Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am reading some exercises that talk about taking a loop in the fundamentla group that generates the whole fundamental group.

But I can not find the definition of generator of fundamental group in my notes, and also I can not find anything in internet. Can someone give a quick explanation about the definition and some intuition behind this concept?

Comment: A generator of a group $G$ is an element $g \in G$ such that $G = \langle g \rangle$. We sometimes say that a loop generates the fundamental group when we really mean that its homotopy class generates the fundamental group.

Comment: It is not a specific concept. The fundamental group is a group. A group can have generators. If a group has a single generator then it is monogenous, so either $\mathbb{Z}$ or a cyclic group.

Comment: The fundamental group of a space is a special kind of [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)). So, if instead you search for "group generators" (instead of a more special search for "generators of the fundamental group"), then you will find the algebraic information you need.

Comment: Thank you y'all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it can happen that a given group $G$ is cyclic. That means that there exists an element $g \in G$ so that every element of $G$ is given as a multiple (under the group operation) of $g$. Up to isomorphism the cyclic groups are exactly the quotient groups of $\mathbb{Z}$ (including the full group and the trivial group).

For arbitrary pointed spaces (if you want you can also assume path-connectedness to make the fundamental group independent of the choice of the basepoint) the fundamental group is not cyclic though and therefore you will not always be able to find/choose a generator. One conrete example where this fails would be the torus $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$ with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Per definition the fundamental group consists of loops up to homotopy and therefore a possible generator will also be a loop (up to homotopy), but as I stated before you will not necessarily find a generator. The intuition you should have would then be the following. Is every loop in your space a multiple of some specific loop (up to continuous deformations). This is true for the circle $S^1$. Every homotopy class of loops here is given by walking around the circle some amount of times (in either clockwise or counterclockwise direction which corresponds to the positive and negative integers).

Comment: And by generator, we mean that generates some classes of homotopic functions, but this does not mean that we can generate all the classes (unless it is cyclic, but I have no idea how to see that a fundamental group is cyclic). Right?

Comment: And If I take a loop, let say in $S^1$, how can I say that that's a generator or not?

Comment: @vicase98 do you know how to prove that the fundamental group of $S^1$ is $\mathbb Z$ or not? There should be a chapter on covering spaces in your book where they prove this result with the help of the map $\mathbb R \rightarrow S^1:r \mapsto e^{2 \pi i r}$

Comment: I have not seen covering spaces yes, but I saw a proof of that using the concepto of path lifting and homotopy liftinh. Honestly, I do not have the intuition behind these concepts

Comment: Yes one can have more than one generator (you could in the worst case just take the entire group as generators). Well depends on the point of view now. If you have computed the fundamental group then you can check whether it is isomorphic to a quotient of the integers. If you (which is more likely) don't know how the fundamental group of your space looks like then you would need to compute it first. This will usually not be trivial and require quite some methods or thoughts.

Comment: @vicase98 of course you don't have intuition, you haven't even read the definitions. And covering spaces allow you to lift homotopies and such, so the proof you saw would essentially have been using covering spaces but not explicitly.

Comment: Ok, I understand the generators more or less now. Hopefully I will see it better later in the course. Thank you everybody!